# Eagle 9.5.x - custom flip-able layers

Tags: eaglecad

The problems seem simple, yet I fail to find an answer...

**Is there a way to create custom flip-able layers in Eagle?**

---

Some background on, what I'm trying to achieve:

I'm working on a project, which requires frequent changes and adaptions to the design. To make my life easier, I want to have a layer for assembly instructions and documentation, for which I create a custom Gerber output in the CAM file (one for topside, one for bottom side).
Like this, all assembly documentation is generated by the CAM output. Also when moving components, the related assembly documentation is moved as well.
I, of course, do not want this documentation on the "Value" and "Name" layers. Also, the "docu" layers are not suitable as I don't want all information from these layers to be in the assembly documentation.
Currently, I created a layer "AssemblyDokuTop" and "AssemblyDokuBottom" and added the necessary information to the parts in the library. 
As long as the components remain on the same side of the boards as in the library the method works fine. But if I have to move components from top to bottom layer, the assembly documentation remains in the original side. This gets especially tricky when I have two instances of the same component on opposite sides of the board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently learned that Eagle has a provision for this case.

The layers 53/54, 55/56, 57/58 and 59/60 are hidden by default. But can be used for custom flipable layers.

Other layers though, don't behave like this.

You can unhide them by using the command:

> LAYER 53 customnametop;
>
> LAYER 54 customnamebottom;